When using a function to add a new node to a linked list, why do i need to return the new node?
Currently I am trying to create a linked list.
Here is the class I am using to create nodes:
class node{
    public:
        int item;
        node* ptr_next;
        node(int new_item = 0, node* new_ptr_next = nullptr):
            item(new_item), ptr_next(new_ptr_next){}
};

Here is the function I have used to add nodes to the tree:
//Adds a node to the end of the linked list.
//by making the last node point to the new node
node append_node(const int& item, node* ptr_entry_node){
    node* ptr_last_node;
    node* ptr_current_node;
    //Finds Last Node In List
    ptr_current_node = ptr_entry_node;
    while (ptr_current_node->ptr_next != nullptr){
        ptr_current_node = ptr_current_node->ptr_next;
    }
    ptr_last_node = ptr_current_node;
    //Instanciates a new node and makes the last node point to the new node
    node new_node(item);
    ptr_last_node->ptr_next = &new_node;
    return new_node;
}

Here is the main program.
int main(){
    //Creates a node for the beggining of the linked list.
    node entry_node;
    append_node(12,&entry_node);
    std::cout<<entry_node.item<<"\n";
    std::cout<<entry_node.ptr_next->item<<"\n";
}

When I run main(), I receive the following output:
0
12


This is the output I expect.
However if I change append_node to:
void append_node(const int& item, node* ptr_entry_node){
        //Exact same code but no "return new_node;"
}

When I run main(), I receive the following output:
0
-1108142424


The second number outputted changes when I run the program again.
This is not what I expect.
I would greatly appreciate your help, if someone could explain why I need to return new_node; in append_node, for the new node to be added to the linked list successfully.

ptr_last_node->ptr_next = &new_node; is a bug. There is no point on storing a pointer to a node that no longer exists after this function ends.

When using a function to add a new node to a linked list, why do i need to return the new node? You don't need to return a pointer to the node however its more convenient for the user of your code if you do. If you didn't then you would have to offer some method to find the last node added.

With both of these comments above said both your append_node methods are flawed and can't possibly work. The first needs to return a node* the second method needs to have this signature: void append_node(const int& item, node*  & ptr_entry_node){ otherwise the node pointer is passed by value and the function works on a copy of that value meaning if the function changed ptr_entry_node the calling function won't see the change.

does return new_node ensure new_node still exists after the function is called?

Use AddressSanitizer if your compiler supports it. Example - As you'll see, even your original program is broken as others have pointed out.

does return new_node ensure new_node still exists after the function is called? No it doesn't

drescherjm. the code does work if I return new_node. However, with regards to your first comment, is there a way i can ensure the new_node still exists after the function ends?

@timmygeorge No, the code has undefined behavior even if you return new_node;. It may look like it works, but you have really no control over what it's doing under the hood.

the code does work if I return new_node Unfortunately sometimes broken code appears to work. This is the worst behavior of undefined behavior. If you called the first version of the code multiple times and changed the values in each node I would expect you to see an unexpected result.

ok, I will try addressSanitizer.

Also remember that you will likely have to dynamically allocate the nodes meaning you will need something like node* myNewNode = new node; in the append_node function. You can not take and store the address of a local variable like I mentioned in the first comment.

Thank you drescherjm, I shall research into dynamic memory allocation and make this change.

As a C++ programmer, you are responsible for understanding the storage of each chunk of data and the lifetime of each object.  The language provides you with some limited tools to help you, but you are free to shoot yourself in the foot, and failing to do this properly often results in difficult to find bugs.  Sadly, this is a significant barrier to learning how to use C++ as a programming language, but it is a requirement, not optional.  Strategies involving "never taking addresses" and "using smart pointers" can help a bit, but even that isn't really sufficient.

Your code stores &new_node in the list, so causes undefined behaviour if subsequent code either traverses that node OR dereferences it.  The return new_node gives a COPY of new_node to the caller. That does NOT change the fact of undefined behaviour - but MIGHT sometimes seem to "work" (you are getting "lucky", but could equally get unlucky).  You really need to correct the cause of undefined behaviour by ensuring all pointers in the list point to objects that continue to exist (e.g. use dynamic allocation, as mentioned). Then the return new_node will not (sometimes) matter

TLDR in practice you wouldn't.. you would use std::list not implement your own class

Do you all actually use shared pointers rather than raw pointers + new + delete?


I shall research into dynamic memory allocation and make this change.

Example code with dynamic memory allocation. It is old code, with the old code names.
#include <iostream>

class node{
    public:
        int item;
        node* next;
        node(int new_item = 0, node* new_next = nullptr):
            item(new_item), next(new_next){}
};

node * append_node(node* list, const int& item){
    node* current;
    node* ptr_new = new node(item);     // dynamically allocate a new node
    if(list == nullptr)                 // if empty list return ptr to new node
        return ptr_new;
    current = list;                     // find end of list
    while (current->next != nullptr){
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = ptr_new;            // append node
    return list;
}

int main(){
    node* list = nullptr;               // empty list
    node* current;
    node* next;
    list = append_node(list, 12);       // allocate and append 2 nodes, display
    list = append_node(list, 34);
    std::cout << list->item <<std::endl;
    std::cout << list->next->item <<std::endl;
    current = list;                     // dynamically free nodes in list
    while (current != nullptr) {
        next = current->next;
        delete current;
        current = next;
    }
    return 0;
}

A better implementation would use a list class that includes pointers to the first and last nodes, a count of nodes (size), and list functions similar to std::list.

Thanks, for the demonstration of how to use new and delete. I plan on making a linked list class soon, once I have done it using functions.
